# Cравнить погрешность вычисления с шагом сетки для него

Tags: c++, c, числа-с-плавающей-точкой, погрешность

Вот какое было полнон условие задачи: **Определить максимальный по модулю член ряда и сравнить погрешность вычисления с шагом сетки для него.** Я написал программу для нахождения масимального элемента ряда и для нахождения шага сетки для него. Как  сравнить погрешность вычисления с шагом сетки для максимального по модулю элемента ряда?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
double my_exp(double x);
double shaq(double c);
int main(void)
{
    double x,c;
    printf("Введи х: "); 
    scanf("%lg",&x);
    c=my_exp(x);
    shaq(c);
   
    return 0;
}

double shaq(double c)
{
    double y,d,eps,p;
    d=fabs(c)+1.;
    do
    {
        y=c+d;
        eps=y-c;
        if(eps!=0)
        p=eps;
        d/=2;
        }
        while(eps>0);
        printf("Шаг сетки=%le\n",p);
        return 0;}

double my_exp(double x)
{
  double sum=1.0, h, eps=1.e-16,z,a; int i=2;
if(x>0){
h=x;
do{
    z=h;
    sum+=h;
    h*=x/i;
    if(abs(z)>=abs(h))
    {a=z;}
    else a=h;
    i++;}
while( fabs(h)>eps );
printf("Максимальный по модулю элемент ряда: %le\n",a);return a;}
else
if(x<0) { 
    h=-x;
do{
    z=h;
    h*=(-x)/i;
    if(abs(z)>=abs(h))
    {a=z;}
    else a=h;
    i++;}
while( fabs(h)>eps );
printf("Максимальный элемент: %le\n",a);return a;}
return 0;
}
```